# List<T> -- Proper Collection to Use for Large Amount of Items?

Tags: c#

**Edit**: Ok, since it's clear I'm taking the wrong approach with this, I'll explain what I was intending to do. The overall intent is to (as an exercise) verify all valid email addresses according to spec. This portion was to generate a portion of the data-set to verify the algorithm against.

---

As an exercise, I'm writing a program that will generate all possible email addresses. This will result in <strike><sub>80</sub><sup>81<sup>65</sup></sup></strike> ≈ 1.4e122 possible items. I'm currently using `List<T>`s to store the generated items but my understanding is that it has a maximum capacity of `Int32.MaxValue`. I'm guessing a proper solution isn't going to involve `List`s of `List`s of `List`s. This is what I have so far.

```
private void GenerateLocalPart()
{
    List<string> validLocalSymbols = new List<string>()
    {
        ".", "!", "#", "$", "%", "&", "*", "+", "-",
        "/", "^", "_", "`", "{", "|", "}", "~", "\"",
    };
    List<string> validLocalNumbers = new List<string>()
    {
        "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
    };
    List<string> validLocalLowercase = new List<string>()
    {
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
        "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
        "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
    };
    List<string> validLocalUppercase = new List<string>()
    {
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
        "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
    };

    List<string> validLocalPartCharacters = new List<string>();
    validLocalPartCharacters.AddRange(validLocalSymbols);
    validLocalPartCharacters.AddRange(validLocalNumbers);
    validLocalPartCharacters.AddRange(validLocalLowercase);
    validLocalPartCharacters.AddRange(validLocalUppercase);

    List<string> targetSequence           = validLocalLowercase;
    int lengthOfStringToGenerate          = 5;
    int numberOfDifferentSourceCharacters = targetSequence.Count;
    List<List<string>> localPart          = new List<List<string>>();
    List<string> localPartSeed            = new List<string>();

    localPart.Add(localPartSeed);
    foreach (string character in targetSequence)
        localPartSeed.Add(character);

    for (int i = 1; i < lengthOfStringToGenerate; i++)
    {
        List<string> bufferList = new List<string>();
        localPart.Add(bufferList);
        foreach (string lastListString in localPart[i - 1])
            foreach (string character in targetSequence)
                bufferList.Add(lastListString + character);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Break here.");
}
```

`lengthOfStringToGenerate` is a maximum length of the strings (so it generates all combinations from 1 to `lengthOfStringToGenerate`). `localPart` will end up with an amount of `List`s equivalent to the `lengthOfStringToGenerate`. Is there a different type of collection that I should be using? Is there a different overall approach I should be taking?

Comment: have you considered the memory implications of storing all of those strings?

Comment: Regardless of data structure, do you have enough RAM / disk for all of those???

Comment: An interesting exercise: approximate how long it's going to take you to generate all those.

Comment: So THAT'S how spammers got my email address...

Comment: Friday is over and so this is not a real question.

Comment: You should explain the problem where you think that generating all possible addresses like this is the solution to. There might be an elegant and actually practical method rather than brute-force.

Comment: @SB , @Rup -- As it turns out, no I don't. @Henk -- could you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: @Leonard: It means I think you're just trolling.

Comment: @Henk: Just to clarify, this was not an attempt at trolling. Could you explain why this came off at trolling? Was it because it was _obviously_ impossible? Unfortunately this wasn't obvious to me, but I think that just means I'm dumb, not a troll.

Comment: You were able to come up with the 1.4e122 estimate, that's not so dumb. I find it hard to imagine someone able to compose this question and not see the problem. Will your next question be about evaluating every chess game?

Comment: You probably don't want a strict email validation. In fact the rules for valid addresses are highly complex. For a start, you might want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Validation

Comment: @Henk - One can be smart yet lack the experience to know the limits of technology.

Comment: @Henk - Oh and you really are a on the edge of trolling.

Comment: @Henk: I'm not sure how to convince you of my intentions. They're not malicious. This is pure oversight on my part. I only came up with that number trying out other solutions to this problem. It _never_ crossed my mind to think about just how large that number actually is. It really just fell under the "durr... big number!" category in my head and I did not realize that I needed to take it into consideration. My priority was to get generation working in the first place.

Comment: The calculation is suppose to be for an 81-token alphabet with a 64 character limit. I discovered that (81 ^ (64 + 1)) / (81 - 1) turns out to be a decent approximation to (81 ^ 64) + (81 ^ 63) + ... 81.

Comment: @0xA3: Thank you for the link. I understand that for practical applications of email validation you would only target a subset of all possible email addresses. This was simply suppose to be a learning exercise to see if I could determine a way to validate _all_ possible valid email addresses. I realize that there more rules to take into consideration and originally intended to integrate those additional rules after I had this working cleanly.

Comment: @Leonard: regardless of your intentions, the answer here is **No** but that makes the question just noise for someone seeking real advice on `List<T>` and large collections. Or Email validation.

Comment: @Henk: I'll agree with you that this question has gone nowhere and probably results in a distraction in its current state. However, by the time I had realized that this made for a poor question, I was already unable to delete the question. What options do I have for resolving this?

Comment: @Leonard: none, don't worry. It may or may not be closed, doesn't matter all that much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Where were you expecting to store all this data? `List<T>` will always store its values in memory... but even if you write something to store the results to disk, you're still not going to be able to hold 1.4e122 items. Have you really taken in just how big that number is? Even at a single bit per item, that's way more than the capacity of the universe, if the whole of the universe was one big hard disk.

The largest unit of data I've ever heard of being talked about in a meaningful way is an exabyte, which is 10<sup>18</sup> bytes. For most people, a petabyte (10<sup>15</sup> bytes) is a pretty huge amount of data. What you're considering makes those quantities seem microscopically small.

What are you trying to *do* with the data afterwards? And when would you expect such an algorithm to ever actually finish?

Comment: Very diplomatic, I am impressed.

Comment: Confirmed: *Universe contains approximately 10^80 atoms* http://pages.prodigy.net/jhonig/bignum/qauniver.html

Comment: @randomguy: Thanks. I wasn't sure, and backed down a little bit in an edit. Will re-edit :)

Comment: @randomguy: But an atom is made of quants (and other stuff we're yet not so sure about), so there might be a certain chance we could... you know.

Comment: Jon, thank you for your answer. Yes, I was expecting to store results to disk. No, I had not really considered how large that number really was. It's unfortunate that I do not have several universe-sized hard disks.

I originally intended to use this as a part of a data-set for a program that would verify whether an email address is valid according to spec (again, as an exercise). The program would use the data-set to test its accuracy -- to ensure that it would match valid addresses and _only_ valid addresses either through a RegEx or whatever algorithm turned out to be most appropriate.

Comment: I realize that there is probably no practical application for this. Most people are fine validating against a subset of email addresses and are more concerned with whether the mailbox _exists_ rather than whether it is valid according to spec. Again, this was mostly an exercise. I did end up learning something in terms of solving problems that I wasn't expecting to learn from this. I learned that I should be considering requirements such as storage and processing time and well... the impossibility of it all.

Comment: @Johannes Rudolph: An atom is not made of quants. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_analyst]  Although some people go from studying atoms to working as a quant.  Perhaps you meant quarks? [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark]

Comment: @Tim Goodman: Yes, sorry. In German (my mother tongue) the distinction is not so sharp. Mixed the two up.

Comment: @Johannes Rudolph: No worries.  On the plus side, I bet you can pronounce names like Schrödinger correctly. I've got a degree in physics and I still can't handle umlauts.

Answer (score 1):

Your project might even be a bigger threat to reality than the LHC and possible micro black-holes, see Arthur C. Clarke’s ‘[The Nine Billion Names of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Billion_Names_of_God)’

Actually, given that your algorithm is entirely deterministic why store the values in the first place? Why not represent them as a in-memory IEnumerable stream that generates the next possible email address each time Next is called. You could store your progress so far (good luck with this) and use the “current position” (or rather “position reached”) as an input to the generator for subsequent runs. As Jon points out, it’s not just a space problem – there’s the total runtime to contend with too (another reason perhaps to use a non-persistent, pull based architecture – assuming you can use the results as they become available then at least this way you’ll derive some useful effect early).

Cute project, one does naturally wonder: why.

Comment: Thanks Tom. If I end up destroying the universe, I'll let you know. This is a good idea and will be something I'll consider if I decide to continue with this project. I could consider testing against a random sampling of generated data instead. I wanted mostly to work on brushing up on RegEx. RegEx seems like it can be quite useful and potentially fast (in development time) to sift through certain kinds of data.